# dplyr filter not filtering entire dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filtering

I have a dataframe called `df` which looks like the following:

| Sample nr | smooth | channel | timepoint | PatientID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA35456 | 24.7361 | fam | 1 | 121 |
| AA35456 | 107.3580 | fam | 1 | 121 |
| AA35456 | 72.0639 | fam | 1 | 121 |
| AA35456 | 43.8766 | vic | 1 | 121 |
| AA35456 | 2382.8700 | vic | 1 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 49.6488 | vic | 1 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 3 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 43.8766 | vic | 3 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 3 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 43.8766 | vic | 3 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 3 | 123 |
| AA35442 | 43.8766 | vic | 3 | 123 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 6 | 126 |
| AA35442 | 43.8766 | vic | 6 | 126 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 6 | 126 |
| AA35442 | 43.8766 | vic | 6 | 126 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 6 | 126 |
| AA35442 | 43.8766 | vic | 6 | 126 |

I have another dataframe called `activefilter` which looks like this

| timepoint | PatientID |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 121 |
| 6 | 124 |
| 3 | 123 |
| 6 | 123 |

the dataframe `df` has around 3million rows and the number of rows in the dataframe `activefilter` depends on the research question.
What i would like to do is subset dataframe `df` based on the activefilter I have tried the following

```
finaldf <- df %>% filter( PatientID == activefilter$PatientID & timepoint == activefilter$timepoint)
```

but this  doesn't work always

1. It sometimes skips patientIDs and timepoints.
2. It only gets a part of the dataframe filtered values. Suppose that i have 50 rows of patientID 121 with timepoint 3, it will return only 17 of those rows.

Is this something that should be done in a for loop?

Comment: could you please `dput()` your dataset.

Comment: Isn't this just `df %>% inner_join(activefilter)`

Comment: @missuse, won't using `%in%` in the OP's filter also include Patients with someone else's timepoint? I think `inner_join` is better here because it explicitly looks for coordination between the two matching columns.

Comment: @missuse, this would include timepoint records of patients that are not supposed to be filtered

Comment: @TarJae I can't due to post length

Comment: @Hedayat, FYI it will be less work for others to use `dput` on the same excerpt of data that you printed in your question -- that way they can load it directly, with the added benefit that they will get the data in the same format as you have it. In some cases it might make a difference whether (for instance) PatientID is an integer, numeric, character, or a factor. Those different data types could all appear the same in the data the way you provided it here, but they would behave differently downstream. `dput` output eliminates those ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TarJae and @akrun's approach is right on -- a semi join or inner join perform exactly what you want, by filtering to just the rows of `df` where `PatientID` and `timepoint` match a row from `activefilter`. Joins are also super fast, so I bet filtering 3M rows will be basically instantaneous.

---

I was curious why your original approach "sort of" worked instead of failing completely. The reason (at least as well as I currently understand it) is that base R will "recycle" vectors. So when you specify `activefilter$PatientID`, you are getting a vector of values from the `PatientID` column in `activefilter`. If that vector is shorter than `df`, it will repeat the vector to fill the difference.

So when you use `filter(PatientID == activefilter$PatientID...)` you are actually asking "Does the first PatientID in `df` match the first `PatientID` in `activefilter`? Does the 2nd PatientID in `df` match the 2nd `PatientID` in `activefilter`?" and so on. If your data is pretty large or if the two data sets have similar sorting patterns, you may get some matches by chance, but you won't get all of them.

As a simpler example, we might look at two of the included data sets in `dplyr`. I've sorted the first one to make it a better example:

```
activefilter <- band_instruments %>% arrange(plays)
df <- band_members

activefilter
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name  plays 
  <chr> <chr> 
1 Paul  bass  
2 John  guitar
3 Keith guitar

df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name  band   
  <chr> <chr>  
1 Mick  Stones 
2 John  Beatles
3 Paul  Beatles
```

Note that both have a `name` column, two entries of which are common to both tables (Paul and John), but only one (John) which matches by position. If we replicate your original code, it will only catch John.

```
df %>%
 filter(name == activefilter$name)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  name  band   
  <chr> <chr>  
1 John  Beatles
```

It would be better to use an inner join or semi join to get the overlap. In your example, `activefilter` has no additional columns than those which are matched with `df`, so they are equivalent. In my example here, the `instruments` table adds another column that doesn't exist in my first table. Inner_join will grab the new column, while semi join will only include the columns from the first table.

One other difference, that @TarJae helpfully pointed out, is that semi_join will identify the rows in `df` that match a row in `activefilter`, whereas `inner_join` will provide duplicate rows if any rows in `activefilter` are repeated. That might or might not happen in your original data, and if so I'm not sure which behavior you want, but FYI.

```
df %>%
  inner_join(activefilter)
Joining, by = "name"
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  name  band    plays 
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> 
1 John  Beatles guitar
2 Paul  Beatles bass  

df %>%
  semi_join(activefilter)
Joining, by = "name"
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name  band   
  <chr> <chr>  
1 John  Beatles
2 Paul  Beatles
```

Comment: thank you so much for explaining this, appreciate it!

Comment: I think `semi_join` is the correct answer in this scenario. `semi_join` subsets `df` into a dataframe with 12 rows consisting with only those rows that match in `activefilter` dataset. If you use `inner_join` than `df` ends with 14 rows. These two rows are duplicates from `activefilter` dataset as `inner_join` puts together all the matching rows.

Comment: @TarJae I can't reproduce what you just stated, I tried semi-join and innerjoin with the dataframes you provided and In both cases i get 12 rows. finaldf <- df %>% 
  semi_join(acitvefilter, by = "PatientID")
finaldf2 <- df %>% 
  semi_join(acitvefilter, by = "PatientID"  )

Answer (score 3):

You should use `dplyr::inner_join` instead of `dplyr::filter`

If you call

```
df %>% inner_join(activefilter)
```

it will give only the rows in `df` that match an entry in `activefilter` based on any shared columns

Comment: Thanks @andrewb this solved the issues for me

Answer (score 1):

This is a scenario for `semi_join`. It returns all rows from x with a match in y.

```
finaldf <- df %>% 
  semi_join(activefilter, by = c("PatientID", "timepoint") 
finaldf
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Samplenr = c("AA35456", "AA35456", "AA35456", 
"AA35456", "AA35456", "AA35444", "AA35444", "AA35444", "AA35444", 
"AA35444", "AA35444", "AA35442", "AA35444", "AA35442", "AA35444", 
"AA35442", "AA35444", "AA35442"), smooth = c(24.7361, 107.358, 
72.0639, 43.8766, 2382.87, 49.6488, 72.0639, 43.8766, 72.0639, 
43.8766, 72.0639, 43.8766, 72.0639, 43.8766, 72.0639, 43.8766, 
72.0639, 43.8766), channel = c("fam", "fam", "fam", "vic", "vic", 
"vic", "fam", "vic", "fam", "vic", "fam", "vic", "fam", "vic", 
"fam", "vic", "fam", "vic"), timepoint = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), PatientID = c(121, 121, 
121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 123, 123, 126, 126, 126, 
126, 126, 126)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
activefilter <- structure(list(timepoint = c(3, 6, 3, 6), PatientID = c(121, 
124, 123, 123)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: This could work too, but i managed to solve it with innerjoin. I am still confused why filter did not give the desired result tho

Comment: Shouldn't the join by `by = c("PatientID", "timepoint")` in which case semi_join and inner_join both work? The OP is trying to match both variables.